# Reading numbers from a txt file and comparing them

Tags: java

With this program I want to read and compare the numbers that I'm given in a text file and print out 
*"buy"* whenever the number goes up three consecutive time and *"sell"* whenever the number goes down three consecutive times.

The problem with my program is that it only reads 13 of the 15 lines of the "numbers.txt" and the buy-sell is at wrong places.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Practise {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int num = 0;
        int up = 0;
        int down = 0;
        int same = 0;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("numbers.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            Double[] array = new Double[15];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < array.length && a + 1 < array.length - 1; a++) {
                num++;
                System.out.print(num + "  " + (array[a]));
                if (array[a] < array[a + 1]) {
                    up++;
                } else if (array[a] > array[a + 1]) {
                    down++;
                } else {
                    same++;
                }
                if ((up >= 3 && (down > 1 || same >= 1))) {
                    System.out.print("  " + "sell");
                    up = 0;
                    same = 0;
                } else if ((down >= 3 && (up > 1 || same >= 1))) {
                    System.out.print("  " + "buy");
                    down = 0;
                    same = 0;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file numbers.txt:

> 26.375
>   25.500
>   25.125
>   25.000
>   25.250
>   27.125
>   28.250
>   26.000
>   25.500
>   25.000
>   25.125
>   25.250
>   26.375
>   25.500
>   25.500

Expected output:

> 1 26.375
>   2 25.500
>   3 25.125
>   4 25.000
>   5 25.250 buy
>   6 27.125
>   7 28.250
>   8 26.000 sell
>   9 25.500
>   10 25.000
>   11 25.125 buy
>   12 25.250
>   13 26.375
>   14 25.500 sell
>   15 25.500

Comment: a<array.length&&a+1<array.length-1   - looks not right at its very least.

Comment: Seems your codes are no more generic. If I change data in text file .. BOOOM>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `a + 1 < array.length - 1`, which can be transformed to `a < array.length - 2`. I guess you understand that the second operand in && limits your iteration to 13.

`a < array.length && a < array.length - 2` = `a < 15 && a < 13` = `a < 13`

I did some minor changes on your code for it to work; you could refactor it a lot, but I stick to your style, so you can better understand the logic.

```
    int num = 1;
    //print the 1st element
    System.out.println(num + "  " + array[0]);
    for (int a = 1; a < array.length; a++) {
        num++;
        System.out.print(num + "  " + (array[a]));
        //plz note that we check with the before, not after
        if (array[a] < array[a - 1]) {
            down++;
        } else if (array[a] > array[a - 1]) {
            up++;
        } else {
            same++;
        }
        //changed down > to down ==
        if ((up >= 3 && (down == 1 || same >= 1))) {
            System.out.print("  " + "sell");
            up = 0;
            same = 0;
        } 
        //changed up > to up ==
        else if ((down >= 3 && (up == 1 || same >= 1))) {
            System.out.print("  " + "buy");
            down = 0;
            same = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answering to OPs comment: if you want to support more than 15 records you can keep adding to a list:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
//if you want to work with array
Double[] array = new Double[list.size()];
array = list.toArray(array);
```

Comment: what u suggested worked, buy and sell went to the right place but my program still prints 13 lines instead of 15.What can i do?

Comment: All good my problem is fixed now buy and sell are in the right place and my program prints 15 lines but i have this :     Double[] array = new Double[15];    Can i change [15] to [args.length] or anything else so i can read more than [15]?

Comment: just updated with the answer to your comment. As you are new to SO, next time you have to specify your full reqs when posting a question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (had to change array to list)

```
int num = 0, up = 0, down = 0, same = 0;

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("numbers.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}

int position = 0;

while (position + 2 < list.size()) {
    Double[] nums = new Double[3];

    System.out.println(nums[0] = list.get(position));
    System.out.println(nums[1] = list.get(position + 1));
    System.out.println(nums[2] = list.get(position + 2));

    if (nums[1] > nums[0] && nums[2] > nums[1]) {
        System.out.println("buy");
        up++;
    } else if (nums[1] < nums[0] && nums[2] < nums[1]) {
        System.out.println("sell");
        down++;
    } else {
        same++;
    }
    position += 2;
}
System.out.println("Ups total: " + up);
System.out.println("Downs total: " + down);
System.out.println("Same total: " + same);
```